# @formular useragent for ibm mobile apps / hcl nomad

Tags: lotus-formula

Most of IBM Notes Application will run within the new hcl nomad / ibm mobile apps iPad client without a change. But the screen resolution is smaller than on notebook or desktop pc.
So i am in need to find a difference between a windows notebook client and an iPad iOS mobile client. I need this mark within in the formular languages so i can use different navigation or diffenrent subforms depending on the users machine.
I tried to use @GetMachineInfo([IsLaptop) (=true) and @getMachineInfo([IsStandard]) (=false), but the result is not different to the result when using a notebook running the basic client instead of the standard client.
Any help would be welcome.

#dominoforever

Comment: #dominoforever is not a megalomanic exclamation but the tag that is used to mark the new domino 10 features and functionalities :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked IBM dev this question recently. Their answer was that @Platform returns "iOS". Haven't checked yet if this is already the case in the beta.

iOS specified APIs like geo coordinate retrieval are not available in the first beta BTW, but will be in later betas.

Comment: Thank You !! That was exactly what i was looking for. Works Great !!

Comment: Here's more information about the app in German language from Detlev Pöttgen: https://www.netzgoetter.net/internet/blogs/netzgoetter.nsf/dx/dominoday-slides-ibm-domino-mobile-apps.htm
Looks like you can also use @Platform([Specific]) to get the exact iOS version, e.g. iOS : 12.1